# How to do rolling window calculations with pandas, so that a new value is calculated every 1 minute

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a `DataFrame` with over 3000 rows that looks like this:

```
                                    rr_ms
time    
2020-03-05 15:43:51.122000+01:00    961
2020-03-05 15:43:52.112000+01:00    946
2020-03-05 15:43:53.131000+01:00    907
2020-03-05 15:43:54.424000+01:00    952
2020-03-05 15:43:54.424000+01:00    968
2020-03-05 15:43:55.298000+01:00    1019
2020-03-05 15:43:56.133000+01:00    1011
2020-03-05 15:43:57.121000+01:00    0
2020-03-05 15:43:58.142000+01:00    1020
2020-03-05 15:43:59.099000+01:00    999
2020-03-05 15:44:00.120000+01:00    948
2020-03-05 15:44:01.441000+01:00    922
2020-03-05 15:44:02.312000+01:00    873
2020-03-05 15:44:02.312000+01:00    899
2020-03-05 15:44:03.184000+01:00    933
2020-03-05 15:44:04.143000+01:00    948
2020-03-05 15:44:05.132000+01:00    986
2020-03-05 15:44:06.124000+01:00    982
2020-03-05 15:44:07.112000+01:00    972
2020-03-05 15:44:08.402000+01:00    0
2020-03-05 15:44:09.363000+01:00    990
2020-03-05 15:44:09.363000+01:00    1069
2020-03-05 15:44:10.233000+01:00    988
2020-03-05 15:44:11.133000+01:00    940
2020-03-05 15:44:12.122000+01:00    870
2020-03-05 15:44:13.112000+01:00    859
2020-03-05 15:44:14.073000+01:00    885
...
```

I would like to calculate a value using `"rr_ms"` just like what is shown in (b) of [this figure](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/core/lw/2.0/html/tileshop_pmc/tileshop_pmc_inline.html?title=Click%20on%20image%20to%20zoom&p=PMC3&id=4501678_pone.0133148.g001.jpg):

- `"rr_ms"` is segmented into 5-minute windows with an increment of 1 minute.
- This means that there is about an overlap of 4 minutes with the neighboring 5 minute segments, resulting in a new value is calculated every minute.
- This also means that the first value appears at the 5-minute mark

I thought that maybe `pandas.rolling()` would give me the result I want, but I think it doesn't behave the way I think it does?

```
IN: df.rolling('5T').sum()

OUT:
                                    rr_ms
time    
2020-03-05 15:43:51.122000+01:00    961.0
2020-03-05 15:43:52.112000+01:00    1907.0
2020-03-05 15:43:53.131000+01:00    2814.0
2020-03-05 15:43:54.424000+01:00    3766.0
2020-03-05 15:43:54.424000+01:00    4734.0
...     ...
```

Desired results would be something like this.

- Note that in the original `df`, the first timestamp is at `15:43`.
- Meaning the first sum (`249022`) is calculated based on the `rr_ms`
  values from `15:43` to `15:47`.
- The second sum (`300041`) is based on the `rr_ms` values from `15:44` to `15:48`.

And so on.

```
                            rr_ms
time    
2020-03-05 15:48:00+01:00   249022
2020-03-05 15:49:00+01:00   300041
2020-03-05 15:50:00+01:00   299396
...
```

I'd love to know what kind of functions I should be using instead.

Comment: You posted result of `df.rolling('5T').sum()` but what is desired output?

Comment: @ipg I've just added the expected result. The first sum is calculated based on the values collected in the first 5 minutes. The second sum is calculate based on the data collected between minute 1 to minute 6, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You should first resample at 1 minute frequency. From that point, you will be able to use a simple `rolling` sum:

```
resul = df.resample('1T').sum().rolling('5T').sum()
```

The sample data would give:

```
                       rr_ms
time                        
2020-03-05 14:43:00   8783.0
2020-03-05 14:44:00  23847.0
```

You can see that the sum is affected to the last minute. If you want to affect it to the first one, just *shift* the index:

```
resul.index = resul.index = resul.index - pd.Timedelta('4min')
```

Comment: Thanks. Does `df.resample('1T')` segment the data into 1-minute windows (i.e., is the result the sum of `rr_ms` in the first minute)?

Comment: @MarielleDado: AFAIK yes. And it is coherent with the results on the sample data.

Comment: Okay, not quite what i was looking for. I would like to segment the data into 5-minute windows so that a new value is calculated at 1-minute increments.

Comment: I was also hoping that the window would "slide" such that each value "shares" about 4 minutes worth of datapoints with the preceding value. I think what you solution came up with sums up a new value every 1 minute, independent of the rest. Kinda hard to explain which is why I included [this figure](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/core/lw/2.0/html/tileshop_pmc/tileshop_pmc_inline.html?title=Click%20on%20image%20to%20zoom&p=PMC3&id=4501678_pone.0133148.g001.jpg) to explain how I'd like the window to behave

Comment: @MarielleDado: Well, `resample('1T')` segments the data into 1-minute windows, and next `.rolling('5T').sum()` compute a rolling sum for 5 consecutive minutes, and for every minute. So *after both operations* 2 adjacent rows do share 4 minutes of data. Just try it on a larger sample and you will see.